# Excel VBA code loop

Tags: vba, excel

How to loop this code so it would start over and over again?

```
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    Sub StartGame()
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        i = 1: j = 1: k = 1

        MoveCar1
    End Sub

    Sub MoveCar1()
        With ws
            Set r = .Cells(6, i)

            r.Cut
            r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            i = i + 1
        End With

        Wait 1

        MoveCar2
    End Sub

    Sub MoveCar2()
        With ws
            Set r = .Cells(6, i)

            r.Cut
            r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            i = i + 1

            Set r = .Cells(8, j)

            r.Cut
            r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            j = j + 1
        End With

        Wait 1

        MoveCar3
    End Sub

    Sub MoveCar3()
        With ws
            Set r = .Cells(6, i)
            r.Cut
            r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            i = i + 1

            Set r = .Cells(8, j)
            r.Cut
            r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            j = j + 1

            Set r = .Cells(10, k)
            r.Cut
            r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            k = k + 1
        End With

        Wait 1

        MoveAllCars
    End Sub

    Sub MoveAllCars()
        For l = 1 To 8
            With ws
                If i < 9 Then
                    Set r = .Cells(6, i)
                    r.Cut
                    r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    i = i + 1
                End If

                If j < 9 Then
                    Set r = .Cells(8, j)
                    r.Cut
                    r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    j = j + 1
                End If

                If k < 9 Then
                    Set r = .Cells(10, k)
                    r.Cut
                    r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    k = k + 1
                End If

                Wait 1

                If i > 8 And j > 8 And k > 8 Then Exit For
            End With
        Next l
    End Sub

    Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
        nSec = nSec + Timer
        While nSec > Timer
            DoEvents
        Wend
    End Sub
```

[You can download it here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1pjkrzzpix2a7l/Car%20Example.xlsm?dl=0#)

This code makes cells (A;6) (A;8) (A;10) move forth, and when they reach cells (I;6) (I;8) (I;10) they stop.

Is it possible to loop this code so it would start over and over again?

Comment: VBA has over half a dozen loop constructs available. Which one have you tried?

Comment: I know, i tried "Loop until" but i dont know how to apply it...

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean with "loop this code", and better describe the behavior you're trying to achieve. You're using `For...Next` and `While...Wend` loops in this code, so I take it that you understand the concept of looping against both a counter and a condition.

Comment: http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html

Comment: This isnt exactly my code... By "loop" i mean so the code would start over and over again, and it would stop only if it encounters a cell that is filled with a word? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it loop that way by putting a loop in your main sub, the one that calls the other subs, but first you need to add another sub to reset the cars to the beginning.

Here is an example of how to reset the cars:

```
Sub ResetCars()
    If i > 8 Or j > 8 Or k > 8 Then
        With ws
            Set r = .Cells(6, i)
            Set s = .Cells(8, j)
            Set t = .Cells(10, k)
            r.Cut
            .Cells(6, 1).Insert
            s.Cut
            .Cells(8, 1).Insert
            t.Cut
            .Cells(10, 1).Insert
        End With
    End If
    If (i > 8 And j > 8 And k > 8) = False Then 'deal with the roadblocks
        bRoadblock = True
        Range("B6:J10").Value = ""
    End If
        Wait 1
End Sub
```

And here is an example of how to do the loop:

```
Sub StartGame()
    bRoadblock = False
    Do Until bRoadblock = True
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        i = 1: j = 1: k = 1

        MoveCar1
        MoveCar2
        MoveCar3
        MoveAllCars
        ResetCars
    Loop
End Sub
```

Notice how I'm calling all of the other subs from the main sub? I deleted those calls from the other subs and put them here. It's a more organized way to do it so that you don't have to follow the chain to figure out how everything fits together. It also helps with conditions. Let's say you decided to exit your MoveCar2 sub based on some criteria. Once you exit, you go to the next thing in the sub where you called that sub. Do you want to do the next thing in the MoveCar1 sub or the main sub?

To loop until there is a roadblock, you need for the loop to know if there's a roadblock. Notice how I put a Boolean in there to tell it as much? You'll also need for the cars to know there's a roadblock and stop for it.

```
If i < 9 Then
    If Len(.Cells(6, i + 1).Value) = 0 Then
        Set r = .Cells(6, i)
        r.Cut
        r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        i = i + 1
    Else
        bRoadblock = True
    End If
End If
```

Something like that could work. It's checking if the next cell's value has a length greater than 0. If so, it stops and sets the roadblock Boolean to true. If not, then it continues like normal.

Please note that there are much better ways to do all of this. I used the style of the rest of your module because you seem like a beginner and I want you to understand the concepts you need to solve your problem. Please don't take that the wrong way. Just keep learning.